# HighslideJS Caption (leftpanel on desktop) and (bottom on mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, css, highslide

I have this website: http://urbanphenomena.net/

For the highslide, I have created a caption which looks nice on desktop on the left side of the images, it displays the same in mobile which is not good looking so I decided to code this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      hs.align = 'center';
      hs.transitions = ['expand', 'crossfade'];
      hs.outlineType = 'rounded-black';
      hs.wrapperClassName = 'dark';
      hs.fadeInOut = true;
      hs.dimmingOpacity = 0.75;
      // Add the controlbar
      if (hs.addSlideshow) hs.addSlideshow({
        //slideshowGroup: 'group1',
        interval: 5000,
        repeat: false,
        useControls: true,
        fixedControls: 'fit',
        overlayOptions: {
          opacity: .75,
          position: 'bottom center',
          hideOnMouseOut: true
        }
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      hs.graphicsDir = 'js/highslide/graphics/';
      hs.captionOverlay.position = "leftpanel";
      hs.captionOverlay.width = "350px";

      if ($(window).width() <= 1000) {
      hs.captionOverlay.width = "150px";
            hs.align = 'left';
      }
    </script>
```

hs.captionOverlay.position = 'leftpanel' is the code responsible for the caption positioning, but if i put that on the if statement, it will look like this in the mobile:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/leRmo.jpg

What do you think the issue is?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Your thread title says you want the caption on the bottom on a mobile, but your code always places the caption in the leftpanel. It just tries to make it narrower on a mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find it easier to come at this from the other direction. Let the caption show below the image (the default), but if the window is *wider* than 1000px, move it to the leftpanel:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Highslide JS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../highslide/highslide.css">
<script src="../highslide/highslide-full.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
hs.graphicsDir = '../highslide/graphics/';
hs.align = 'center';
hs.transitions = ['expand', 'crossfade'];
hs.outlineType = 'rounded-white';
hs.fadeInOut = true;
hs.addSlideshow({
    interval: 5000,
    repeat: false,
    useControls: true,
    fixedControls: 'fit',
    overlayOptions: {
        opacity: .75,
        position: 'bottom center',
        hideOnMouseOut: true
    }
});
if($(window).width() > 1000) {
    hs.captionOverlay.position = 'leftpanel';
    hs.captionOverlay.width = '200px';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="highslide-gallery">
<a href="../images/gallery1.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
    <img src="../images/gallery1.thumb.jpg" alt="Highslide JS" title="Click to enlarge"></a>
<div class="highslide-caption">Caption for the first image. This caption can be styled using CSS.</div>
<a href="../images/gallery2.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
    <img src="../images/gallery2.thumb.jpg" alt="Highslide JS" title="Click to enlarge"></a>
<div class="highslide-caption">Caption for the second image.</div>
<a href="../images/gallery3.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
    <img src="../images/gallery3.thumb.jpg" alt="Highslide JS" title="Click to enlarge"></a>
<div class="highslide-caption">Caption for the third image.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You, are AWESOME!

Comment: Thanks! I gave it a quick little test, and it seems to work. The catch, of course, is that if you're playing around with resizing the window, you have to do a refresh each time, since none of this responds dynamically. I've seen a kludge to make Highslide JS respond to window size changes "live," but the results were really awful!